# Unable to group ColumnDataSource Data by color in Bokeh .rect glyph

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like to group my plot by color based on a column that holds strings in a .csv file.
I was under the impression that "color = 'ColumnName'" would work.

```
p.rect(x = range(len(source.data['Project Description'])),
   y = adj_h,
   color= 'Client',
   source = source,
   width = .4,
   height = 'Budget'     
  )
```

This just has my rectangle glyphs appear with black outlines and no fillcolor.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors in Bokeh are plotted using a color mapping scheme. First you need to set the colormap which allows Bokeh to know what color to use for which object. You can either manually set the colormap by using a dictionary `colormap = {'Client_1':'red', Client_2:'blue'}` or if you can use the built in `CategoricalColorMapper` function to create a colormap `colormap = CategoricalColorMapper(palette=palette, factors=list_of_factors)`.

Then you can specify the colors in the plotting function. Either you can use a list containing all the colors for all data points `colors = [colormap[x] for x in source['Client']]` and then pass the colors to the plot `color=colors`. Or you can let bokeh do the transformation for you with directly in the plot function `color={'field': 'Client', 'transform': colormap}`

---

In your code, I'd try something like

```
colormap = CategoricalColorMapper(palette=palette, factors=list(set(data['Client'])))

p.rect(x = range(len(source.data['Project Description'])),
   y = adj_h,
   color = {'field': 'Client', 'transform': colormap}',
   source = source,
   width = .4,
   height = 'Budget'     
  )
```

Where the palette is chosen depending on the number of categories and data is your original dataset.

---

References:

[iris.py](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/iris.html) - Example on manually setting colors to each item in the dataset and using the list of colors in the plot.

[texas.py](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html) - Example using the palette and color mapper and then letting the plotting function set the colors with `'transform'`.

Comment: Happy to help @Jamm6, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.